# Why isn't MongoDB simple read query working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm making an application with a server using express and mongodb. I was previously doing just fine developing this application, until with one small change none of my queries are working to mongodb. I triple checked my connection string, and the output on postman is getting to that function, yet never triggering the mongodb query callback.

Here is my server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const authenticationController = require("./controllers/authenticationController");
const mainActionsController = require("./controllers/mainActionsController");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// all user actions
app.use("/auth", authenticationController);

app.use("/memoryleak", mainActionsController);

// Fail safe. Here's our classic 404 error :P
app.all("*", (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(404)
    .send(
      "Sorry, the content you were looking for was not found. The classic 404 "
    );
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});

module.exports = { app };
```

Here is a snippet of my mainActionsController which is triggered above and uses a router...

```
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Questions, Replies, Users } = require("../dbschema");
const repliesController = require("./repliesController");
const questionController = require("./questionController");
const notificationController = require("./notificationsController");

router.get("/getQuestionById/:id", (req, res) => {
  questionController.getQuestionById(req, res, Questions, mongoose);
});
router.get("/questions", (req, res) => {
  questionController.getAllQuestions(req, res, Questions);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my getAllQuestions function:

```
const getAllQuestions = (req, res, Questions) => {
  console.log("got to the correct function");
  Questions.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    console.log("hello? CAN YOU HEAR ME");
    console.log(err, docs);
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
    console.log(docs);
    return res.status(200).send(docs);
  });
};
```

All those console logs are reached when route is hit by postman, but nothing inside of the callback function are ever logged, and the connection just suspends.

Last of all, here is my db schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  passWord: { type: String, required: true },
  questionsAsked: { type: Array, required: true },
  repliesGiven: { type: Array, required: true },
  itemsLiked: { type: Array, required: true },
  notifications: { type: Array, required: true }
});
const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  questionBody: { type: String, required: true },
  numReplies: { type: Number, required: true },
  numLikes: { type: Number, required: true },
  numVotes: { type: Number, required: true },
  tags: { type: Array, required: true },
  contributor: { type: String, required: true }
});
const ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
const ReplySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  questionID: ObjectId,
  title: String,
  questionBody: String,
  numLikes: Number,
  numVotes: Number,
  contributor: String
});

mongoose.model("Reply", ReplySchema);
mongoose.model("Question", QuestionSchema);
mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = {
  Questions: mongoose.model("Question"),
  Replies: mongoose.model("Reply"),
  Users: mongoose.model("User")
};[1]
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the "small change" that broke it?

Comment: Are mongod process running ?

Comment: Check if the mongod process is running and maybe connect to the mongo shell and check if your query runs.

Comment: I got it. It was because I had a file containing the connection string to mongodb, however that file wasn't being required into the server so it wasn't connecting properly. Thanks!